# Ajax call that will put a click event into a php variable to avoid the window.open() method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery scrip which counts the number of clicks on a certain div and then, at the second click, it redirects the user to a custom url.
The script works and counts the clicks even if the user leaves the page.

```
function traffic(){
    var traffic = $('.model').data("traffic");
    if(traffic){
        var nbc = localStorage['nbc']||0;
        $('.model a').click(function(){
            localStorage['nbc'] = ++nbc;
            if(nbc%2==0){
                window.open(traffic, '_blank');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, I am a total newb with ajax (actually i do not know anything about it, I am a webmaster not a programer with an overdue deadline) and I need some help:

I need an **ajax call that, on the time of the action, will send the second click into a php variable** so I can use a code like the following (and avoid the "window.open" method which is in conflict with another script I use on the page):

```
   if($number_of_clicks == 2){
       echo 'my new link, a method which will save me from using window.open';
   } else {
       echo 'my ragular link';
   }
```

Can it be done?

**UPDATE**

Let me explain, my fault for not being clearer.

User enters my site and clicks on a normal link. Jquery stores that event and the user goes to an internal page.

When he hits the home button, ajax sends that event to a php variable, so I'll have $myvar=1.

Now I can change that certain link on my site with:

```
if($myvar == 1){
           echo 'my new link';
       } else {
           echo 'my ragular link';
       }
```

And now, when the user clicks on that link, he will go to the new link.

Hope I've been a little clearer.

Ty!

Comment: What do you plan to do in php that would save you from using window.open?

Comment: can you use jQuery on your site?

Comment: @BuddhiP He is using jquery from the code !!

Comment: the window.open method conflicts with another script. So I need jquery to populate a php variable only when the user clicked once. After the first click, I'll have a variable like $myvar = 1; and then I could use the php code. Not sure this can be done

Comment: my bad!! :( Didn't notice it. :)

Comment: @webmasters - what would that PHP code **do**?

Comment: I have updated the question, trying to be clearer.

Comment: You don't need any kind of ajax or php involved, you can create the link from within javascript directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get a click to PHP is to just an AJAX request. EG:

```
$.get('/clickonce.php');
```

and then in PHP you could do:

```
<?php
$myvar = 1;
?>
```

But this wouldnt be perfect. The clickonce.php code will be called, but there is a delay since it's a new page request, so with slow internet/server responds it could be more then a few seconds before it is actually logged.

Considering that your window.open is conflicting with another script, which I assume is javascript, i would go for a javascript solution.

```
var clickedOnce = false;
function traffic(){
    var traffic = $('.model').data("traffic");
    if(traffic){
        var nbc = localStorage['nbc']||0;
        $('.model a').click(function(){
            localStorage['nbc'] = ++nbc;
            if(nbc%2==0){
                window.open(traffic, '_blank');
            } else {
                clickedOnce = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

now in your other javascript script you can check for `if (!clickedOnce) { //do something }`

Comment: Very interesting, let me test it. You could be right about jquery being in conflic with javascript. That other script is in javascript. And you are also right about the delay with ajax, since I call jquery async also.

Comment: By the way, the conflict only happens in internet exlorer. Mozilla works perfectly

Comment: Your not using IE 7? localStorage is only supported from IE 8

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply make an AJAX get request using jQuery.

```
$.get('/your.php', function(url) {
     // value echoed by your php page will be available in the url variable passed into this function.
     // You can do what you want with it.
     alert(url);
});
```